# Primefaces SelectOneMenu resets and fires change event on Ctrl press

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2, selectonemenu, ctrl

Using PF 6.0, JSF 2.2

Simple Example with `<p:selectOneMenu>` :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="priority" filter="true" tabindex="38"  disabled="#{inquiryManagedBean.readOnly}" appendTo="@this" value="Priority" valueChangeListener="#{inquiryManagedBean.valueChangePriority}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Select--" itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{codeListMBean.codelistItems}"/>
    <p:ajax event="change" partialSubmit="true" process="@this" update="changeofAssignTo" listener="#{inquiryManagedBean.mandatoryValidation}"/> 
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

On <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> when focus is on `<p:selectOneMenu>` then value is resetting to default value  Select.

**Issue:** Auto Default selection of `<p:selectOneMenu>` is happening only when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> and release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> immediately.

**Note:** When I am pressing Up <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> and not releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> immediately, It works as expected.

Actual Functionality of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>S</kbd> in our application is a shortcut to Submit the `<form>`.

Why this wicked behavior of PF 6.0 and How to avoid it?

Please suggest anything for this.

Comment: What happens with other key combinations?

Comment: @Kukeltje With other key combination also same problem `<p:selectOneMenu>`  value is resetting to default value.